# How long is the battery life of a GPS tracker, when used to detect motion only?

Tags: sailing, gps, theft

I was looking at GPS Trackers such as Spark Nano 4.0. I wanted to apply one of these devices inside my boat to exclusively use it for motion detection in case of theft.

The battery life of this device is of 2 weeks, for accurate tracking in movement. But I can't find how long it last for the motion detection task.

I'm planning to deactivate it then, when I'm sailing to save the battery.

Comment: Why would you want exact motion detection when sailing?

Comment: @HTDutchy For when my boat is on the dock

Answer (score 2):

Sources:
http://gps-tracker-review.toptenreviews.com/spark-nano-details.html
http://sparkgps.com/

Reading up on the device and from simple knowledge.
I'd say device life would largely depend on the update frequency.
The device will always easily acquire a GPS fix with an accuracy of at least 5-10 meters.

I couldn't find the default interval to quickly but I assume that you can easily get more then 2 weeks when updating every 2 hours or so. (should be enough unless you're dealing with a racing cat)

Comment: Hi! This link is dead. Now that the question's active again, might you want to change it to something else? Thanks!